# Why do I get the following error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: android

I have the following XML:

```
<TextView
 android:layout_y="20dip"   
 android:layout_x="20dip"

 androd:gravity="fill"
 android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
 android:background="#4F2F4F"
 android:layout_height="335dip" 
 android:layout_width="270dip"
 />

 </AbsoluteLayout>
```

This gives me the error `Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mistyped `android` in `androd:gravity="fill"`

Comment: happens to the even best of us...and I'm not one of the best....so it happens more often.